# incollection with biblatex-chicago shorthand collection not showing author or title

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

I am running into an issue that it appears was foreseen in `biblatex-chicago` in section 4.2 under `shorthand`.

My problem is that in my field, there are a few collection works that are commonly referred to in citations by a shorthand. However, each entry has its own author and title. So in each footnote, I need the title, author, and then the reference to the collection should be a shorthand.

It looks like in the `biblatex-chicago` manual under `shorthand` in section 4.2 that I should "use the shorthandintro field somehow to clarify that the shorthand applies to the parent rather than to the child."

First, I am not sure what that means. Second, my style requires that all shorthands are cited as the shorthand on the first entry, so I have the `shorthandfirst` option in my package options. So I am unsure what `shorthandintro` would even do. (I tried setting it to something, but nothing happens, probably because I have `shorthandfirst` set).

Here is a MWE of what I am seeing:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes} 

\usepackage[noibid,backend=biber,notes,isbn=false,shorthandfull,shorthandfirst,inheritshorthand=true,citereset=chapter,longcrossref=bib]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
    @collection{bigbook,
        editor = {John Q. Editormann},
        title  = {A Collection of Essays},
        shorthand = {ACoE},
        options   = {skipbib},
        publisher = {Oxford University Press},
        address = {Oxford},
        year = {1995}}
    @incollection{incol,
        crossref = {bigbook},
        options  = {skipbiblist},
        author   = {Steve Authormann},
        title    = {This is an Essay},
        pages    = {1-15}}
    @incollection{incol2,
        crossref = {bigbook},
        options  = {skipbiblist},
        author   = {John Essaymann},
        title    = {An Essay on Collections},
        pages    = {16-30}}
    \end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\begin{document}
\printbiblist{shorthand}
\null\vfill
I need to reference this in a footnote.\footcite[12]{incol} But this is
another footnote.\footcite[18]{incol2} I need the second footnote
twice.\footcite[20]{incol2}
\clearpage
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is what I see in the footnotes and bib:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have no idea why a subsequent reference uses the author last name, which in the first instance it uses ACoE.

If I comment out the shorthand in the `collection` entry, I see this (obviously the LoA goes away, and the bib remains unchanged):
[image]

But I need a combination of these styles. I need the style of the second example, where in the first two footnotes it lists author and title, but both footnotes should be "in ACoE" and then the page numbers.

I know that the author of `biblatex-chicago` recommends against shorthands with cross references, but my style requires using the shorthand of the collection in incollection. I have many, many of these incollections so I would prefer to still be able to use `crossref` to link to only one `collection` entry, if possible.

A second issue, that I think is much harder to solve, is that in subsequent references (footnote 3), I need both author and the collection abbreviation. So footnote three above is wrong in both instances. It should say something like "Essaymann, ACoE, 20."

This I think is harder to solve and would require a new entry type, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update** with your new requirements (not much needs to change).

It's not ideal, but probably the *easiest* way to do this is simply to construct the citations by hand. You can use a macro that deals with subsequent citations. The `\paul@blx@trackentry@global` macro allows me to manually add an entry to the list of seen entries (at global scope). This is needed because the citation construction building blocks don't do this automatically.

I made a more `\cite`-like macro using `xparse`.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage[variant=us]{english}
\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}

\usepackage[noibid,backend=biber,notes,isbn=false,shorthandfull,shorthandfirst,inheritshorthand=true,longcrossref=bib,minxrefs=1]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{temp.bib}
@collection{bigbook,
    editor = {John Q. Editormann},
    title  = {A Collection of Essays},
    shorthand = {ACoE},
    options   = {skipbib},
    publisher = {Oxford University Press},
    address = {Oxford},
    year = {1995}}
@incollection{incol,
    crossref = {bigbook},
    options  = {skipbiblist},
    author   = {Steve Authormann},
    title    = {This is an Essay},
    pages    = {1-15}}
@incollection{incol2,
    crossref = {bigbook},
    options  = {skipbiblist},
    author   = {John Essaymann},
    title    = {An Essay on Collections},
    pages    = {16-30}}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{temp.bib}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \IfEmptyF \tl_if_blank:nF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\makeatletter
\def\paul@blx@trackentry@global#1{%
  \ifbool{citetracker}
    {\blx@xsanitizeafter{\def\sbl@blx@tempa}{#1}%
     \xifinlistcs{\sbl@blx@tempa}{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}
       {}
       {\listcsxadd{blx@bsee@\the\c@refsection}{\sbl@blx@tempa}}}
    {}}
\let\paul@blx@trackentry\paul@blx@trackentry@global

\NewDocumentCommand{\shortincolcite}{o o m}{%
  \footnote{%
    \IfNoValueF{#1}{\IfNoValueF{#2}{#1 }}%
    \blx@imc@ifentryseen{#3}
      {\citeauthor{#3}, }
      {\citename{#3}[default]{labelname}, \citetitle{#3}, in
       \paul@blx@trackentry{#3}}%
    \citefield{#3}{shorthand}%
    \IfNoValueTF{#2}{, #1}{\IfEmptyF{#2}{, #2}}.}}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
I need to reference this in a footnote.\shortincolcite[See][]{incol}
But this is another footnote.\shortincolcite[See][18]{incol2}
I need the second footnote twice.\shortincolcite[20]{incol2}
\printbiblist{shorthand}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks @david-purton! I notice that you do not crossref the bigbook if the incol. I was actually wrong in my MWE, in that I want the individual articles in the bib, but not the bigbook. The big book should only show up in a list of abbreviations. If the incols are not crossref'd, then the bibliography is wrong. Is there a way to do it and get the bibliography correct? I updated my MWE(which actually gives a different wrong footnote that I don't understand). Sorry for the confusion and error!

Comment: Wow, thanks so much! That is perfect.

Comment: two small questions: 1) What is the benefit of using IfNoValueF over IfValueT since it should be boolean either way? Just preference? 2) If a pre-note is given, but no postnote, my guess is that the page numbers from the bib entry should be used since it is an incollection (page numbers can be assumed I believe). I can get this with \citefield I guess (and put it in a true path of IfEmptyF{#2}{, #2}?

Comment: I figured out the second question by making a new command \cs_set_eq:NN \IfEmptyTF \tl_if_blank:nTF.

Comment: I confess I didn't really give thought either way with `\IfNoValueTF`. `\IfValueTF` would work just as well. The `pages` field should be printed, at least on first citation (See https://sblhs2.com/2018/02/08/citing-page-numbers-for-chapters-and-articles/). I used to print it on subsequent citations with `biblatex-sbl`, but found that this had potential to create confusing, ambiguous, or plain wrong citations, so I changed it so that the `pages` field never prints with subsequent citations. See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/93

Comment: Hmmm interesting. I am not sure. I left a comment on that issue even though it is closed. You can let me know what you think.